# Is there a way to Pivot Chart Min, Max, & Avg values after creating a Pivot to Sum?

Tags: excel, csv, pivot, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am using excel to merge a series of daily csv datasets with pivot.

The data set has multiple runtime values for specific names on specific dates.

I have built a pivot table to sum those values correctly.

I now have a table that displays the sum values with specific names on the Y axis and specific dates on the X axis.

*(Please see below for a sanitized screenshot of the pivot table.)*

Is there a way to take this data and display it as Min, Max, & Avg within a pivot chart *(after the values have been summed as described above)*?

[image: Pivot Table Screenshot]